# LWC displays data from apex even if access to apex class is blocked

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have inserted LWC in visualforce page using lightning out. I want to hide the LWC to some profiles.  I removed the access of apex class that LWC uses for those profiles hoping the LWC will hide, but it still shows up. I was looking for a better option to hide LWC other that using custom permissions. Is there any?

Updates:
I am displaying the LWC in lead record VF page using lightning out. This is the code I am currently using to check custom permission before rendering the LWC.

```
<apex:includeLightning />                                                         
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!$Permission.Potential_Duplicates_LWC}"> //check permission
    <div id="lwcDemo" />  //display LWC
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Do you have an option to control the visibility of the VF page? wheres this VF page shown?

Comment: @RedDevil the VF page is displayed on lead detail page. The LWC is inserted inside the page. I have updated the question with the details. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of [VF security](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_page_level_security.htm&type=5) :

> Permission for a Visualforce page is checked at the top level only.
>   Once users can access a page, they can execute all Apex that’s
>   associated with the page. This includes:
>
> 1. The controller for the page and any Apex classes called from the
>      controller class.
> 2. Any extension classes for the page and any Apex
>      called from an extension.
> 3. Any Apex classes associated with custom
>      components within the page. Any classes associated with the page
>      through the use of apex:include or apex:composition.

This does not specify about lightning component inside VF, but in general SF rule, if you can access VF page you can access everything inside.

A solution would be to use `rendered` tag and check profiles or custom permission and then only display lwc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hiding the component using `slds-hide` / `slds-show`with css? You can get the profile/user ids you want from the apex controller and hide the component based on the logic you need.

```
<template>
    <span class={cssDisplay}>
        <div id="spinnerDiv" class="demo-only demo--inverse" style="height: 10rem">
        <div class="slds-spinner_container">
            <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_medium">
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </span> 
</template>
```

[SLDS Visibility](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/visibility/)

Comment: the issue with css hiding is it can be bypassed by just inspect... blocking it from server-side would be best.